# calculating the sum of input numbers in c language

Tags: c, pointers

I want to calculate the sum of input numbers using pointer concept in c language.But when i compile the given below program correct value for sum does not appear. help  me to find the mistake i have done in the below program.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{   
    int g , *p;

    int sum = 0;

    int x=1;

    for(int i=1; i<3; i++ )
    {   
        scanf("%d ", &g);       
    }

        p = &g;

    while( x < 3){
    sum =  sum + *p;
    p++;
    x++;
    }

    printf("\n sum = %d ",sum);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `g` is only ***one*** integer so:

1. Each time you call `scanf("%d ", &g);`, you will *overwrite* the previous value.
2. When you increment the pointer in `p++;`, that pointer will no longer be valid. (Where do you think it will point to?)

If you want to store three *different* values in `g`, you need to make it an *array* of integers.

To do this, make the following changes to your code:

```c
int g[3] , *p; // "g" can now store three different values
int x=0; // Later on - counting from 0 thru 2 in the "while" loop
//...
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) // NOTE: Arrays begin at "0" in C!
{   
    scanf("%d ", &g[i]); // Store to the element indexed by "i"       
}
//...
p = g; // For arrays, don't need the & operator: this will give address of first element
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store only one number in `g`.

Therefore, `p++;` here will make `p` point at an invalid place.

You should allocate an array to store all input values.

Also note that you should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    int g[3] , *p;

    int sum = 0;

    int x=1;

    for(int i=1; i<3; i++ )
    {   
        scanf("%d ", &g[i]);
    }

        p = &g[1];

    while( x < 3){
    sum =  sum + *p;
    p++;
    x++;
    }

    printf("\n sum = %d ",sum);

}
```

Comment: Arrays begin at ***zero*** in C.

Comment: that space in scanf wont effect it? i think it takes another value?

Comment: @AdrianMole You don't have to use the first element of the array.

Comment: You do if you want to add three numbers.

Comment: @AdrianMole No, you don't. You can allocate `g[4]` and use `1, 2, 3` if it is easier to understand for you.

Comment: Of course, but I *think* OP wants three numbers, so a `g[3]` array seems better.